# Trying to add a DISTINCT COUNT column in table to INNER JOIN query SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

So I am querying a basketball dataset and I'm using an INNER JOIN statement to get the season stat lines for each Rockets player. However, I am also trying to get a count of how many games they played in the season putting that in a column to get a count of games played for each player.

I'm still learning so I'm trying to experiment and put queries together until I'm stumped. Having trouble with nested queries, thank you in advance.

Pictures:
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4TFc.png), [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCUr0.png)

```sql
-- Houston Rockets team_id = 1610612745
-- Jalen Green player_id = 1630224
SELECT player.player_name, player_season.*
FROM player_season
(
SELECT 
DISTINCT COUNT (player_id)
FROM player_game_log
AS games_played
)
INNER JOIN
    player
    ON player_season.player_id = player.player_id
WHERE player_season.team_id = 1610612745
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the subquery directly in the SELECT statement like this:

```
SELECT player.player_name,
       (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(player_id)
        FROM   player_game_log
        WHERE  player_game_log.player_id = player.player_id) AS games_played,
       player_season.*
FROM   player_season
       INNER JOIN player
               ON player_season.player_id = player.player_id
WHERE  player_season.team_id = 1610612745
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For clarification, I get the `AS games_played` would be to alias the `COUNT` of the subquery, what role does the `,player_season.*` part play?

Comment: No problem. You are correct that you have to open/close it with parentheses. I did that in my example. I just simply moved it up into outer most `SELECT` statement and used the `player.player_id` from that outer `SELECT` in the subqueries `WHERE` clause. The subquery is basically used to create a new column in the result set. Please mark this as answered if it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, didn't see the Answered button either lol. Taking my time to translate this query to plain English in my head, thank you so much.

Comment: To answer your second question, you are correct about the alias and as for the `player_season.*` portion of the `SELECT` statement, it simply selects ALL of the rows in the `player_season` table after the subquery column. If you remove the `player_season` table and keep the `*`, the query will return ALL columns from ALL tables after the `FROM` (i.e. `player_season` and `player` tables). Another option is to specify what exact columns from either the `player_season` or `player` you want.

Comment: Ahhh I see so `,player_season.*` is just the continuation of the outer `SELECT` statement? So if I were to remove the subquery and the new column, it would just be `SELECT player.player_name, player_season.*`?

Comment: Yup, that's correct! It would take the `player.player_name` from the `player` table and ALL columns from the `player_season` table.